# debug a big loop in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I am debugging a Python program in Eclipse.

I have a breakpoint in a big loop and I expect the problem to occur in the (1000+)th round. How can I reach that ASAP instead of clicking `resume` 1000 times?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to set a [conditional breakpoint](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_debugger.html).  Read through the link I provided for an explanation and example in python.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-R is the equivalent to placing a breakpoint on the cursor's line and clicking the "Resume" button, except that it doesn't litter your system with unnecessary breakpoints.

Is this what you are looking for?

Take a look at this: http://www.clear.rice.edu/comp310/Eclipse/debugging.html